# Multiple headers issue with JavaMail addRecipient method

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-headers

A mail server returns this error when I send mail with several recipients :

> Remote Server returned 'mx.spamexperts.com #5.0.0 smtp; 550 Messages should have one or no To headers, not 5.'

It happens when I use `addRecipient` method of JavaMail multiple times. If I use `setRecipient` instead with an array of email address, it works.

This is the consequence of the `addHeader` method in `javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders` class. Here is the piece of code which is the cause of this issue :

```
for (int i = headers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    InternetHeader h = (InternetHeader)headers.get(i);
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(h.getName())) {
    if (addReverse) {
        pos = i;
    } else {
        headers.add(i + 1, new InternetHeader(name, value));
        return;
    }
    }
    // marker for default place to add new headers
    if (h.getName().equals(":"))
    pos = i;
}
```

What do you think about that ? Why JavaMail adds new `To` header each time we use `addRecipient` if some mail server does not accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using a very old version of JavaMail.  This was fixed in JavaMail 1.4.4, over 5 years ago.  The [current version is 1.5.5](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: Damn, you're right! I didn't even think about the version of JavaMail I'm using... Indeed it was the 1.4.1, a very old one... Thanks!